# How to mask out an object behind another transparent object?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

I want to set up an a-frame AR scene where you can see an object through a hole in the table. I built a box with a hole on top in Cinema 4D and now I need to have a material which is transparent but doesn`t rendering objects behind. Any ideas?

Cheers, Can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also if you want to hide a GLTF/ GLB model behind a plane because material="opacity" only works on primitives then I suggest you also include
this component in your script and attach it to your model:

```
  AFRAME.registerComponent('model-opacity', {
  schema: {default: 1.0},
  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', this.update.bind(this));
  },
  update: function () {
    var mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
    var data = this.data;
    if (!mesh) { return; }
    mesh.traverse(function (node) {
      if (node.isMesh) {
        node.material.opacity = 1;
        node.material.transparent = true;
        node.material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

// YOUR AFRAME MOCKUP WOULD BE

```
<a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" material="transparent: true;"></a-box>

<!--- this one will mask all following objects ---!>
<a-plane position=".2 0 0" rotation="0 180 0" material="transparent: true; opacity: 0.2;"></a-plane>

     <a-entity id="model"
                gltf-model="#3Dmodel"
                rotation="0 0 0"
                scale=".8 .8 .8"
                position="0 -1 .4"
                model-opacity>

<!--- the sphere won't be visible behind the transparent plane ---!>
<a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" material="transparent: true;"></a-sphere>
```

Answer (score 1):

A neat trick is exploiting the rendering order. With a setup like this:

```
<a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" material="transparent: true;"></a-box>

<!--- this one will mask all following objects ---!>
<a-plane position="0 1.3 -1" material="transparent: true; opacity: 0.2;"></a-plane>

<!--- the sphere won't be visible behind the transparent plane ---!>
<a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" material="transparent: true;"></a-sphere>
```

The sphere won't be visible behind the plane.

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mks2xcr1/4/). The way of dealing with this (i stumbled upon it while playing with simple `.png` files), would be setting the alpha-test value: `material="alphaTest: 0.5"`. Like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mks2xcr1/6/).

Comment: Hi Piotr, thanks again! :) First I was afraid I need to write a opengl depth-shader for this and then I tumbled over the opacity issue too. I had to change the 3d-model from collada to obj and now it works perfect! Cheers, Can

Comment: On a `THREE` level it would've been better to play around with depths, but for `aframe` purposes it should be sufficient :)